# Creating conditional comments with XSLT?

Tags: internet-explorer, xslt, conditional-comments

I want to create [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) in XSLT.

But when I use this:

```
<!-- [If IE7] [endif] -->
```

in an `<xsl:comment>`, XSLT removes it from the output when it is rendered.

Is there any way to create conditional comments in XSLT?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply use an `<xsl:comment>` tag and include your comment within the tag.

For example:

```
<xsl:if test="@id = '1'">
  <xsl:comment>
    <![CDATA[[if IE]><![endif]]]>
  </xsl:comment>
</xsl:if>
```

[Taming Your Multiple IE Standalones](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/multiIE.html) is a great article on this subject.

Comment: Yeah.. It works :)

Why you used first line of Code? <xsl:if test="@id='a'">

Comment: The <xsl:if> ? I thought that you needed the comment to be included conditionally! Where's my vote/acceptance ?!  ;-)

Comment: Vote added. ;-) A conditional comment is included unconditionally. But IE evaluates the comment as a conditional -- if it evaluates to true, the code within gets executed.

Comment: How to get dynamic values inside comments

Answer (score 6):

The above solution assumes that the content inside the conditional comment does not contain any XSLT parameters. In the example below we're having a parameter `$DATA_ROOT_PATH` that should be processed to give us the correct location of a CSS file. In this case `<xsl:comment/>` is not suitable. We must use `<xsl:text/>` and disable the output escaping.

The example here will include the CSS file only if we're using IE7.

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--[if IE 7]&gt;</xsl:text>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$DATA_ROOT_PATH}/resources/css/ie7.css" media="screen"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![endif]--&gt;</xsl:text>
```

The code example would generate output like so if `$DATA_ROOT_PATH` = */example*:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="/example/resources/css/ie7.css"
        media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You wrote _"<xsl:comment/> is not suitable"_, but it is as per http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Comments : _"`<!-- Category: instruction -->
<xsl:comment>
  <!-- Content: template -->
</xsl:comment>

`"_ It means that you can use any content template inside `xsl:comment` instruction as long as it output nothing else than text nodes.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid scenario, when you need to process the contents of the conditional comment further. There is a typo with the closing tag though: There are two extra `]]` characters after the endif. Correctly it should say: `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![endif]--&gt;</xsl:text>`

Answer (score 0):

This was the only way I was able to get my ie stylesheet to be applied:

```
    <xsl:comment>[if IE]>
      &lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
      &lt;![endif]</xsl:comment>
```

I had to make sure there is no space between my text and the xsl:comment opening/closing tags